# syntax error near unexpected token `fi'

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

When i am trying to execute the below shell command, i am getting exception as below

```
bash: ./qa_domain_pdp_auto_startup_script.sh: line 11: syntax error near unexpected token fi
bash: ./qa_domain_pdp_auto_startup_script.sh: line 11: fi;
```

below is sh file.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "starting execution"
domain_pdp_process_id=`/bin/ps -fu "pdpadmin"|grep "/home/pdpadmin/app/payara41/glassfish/domains/pdp/"|grep -v "grep" | awk '{print $2}'`
echo "getting process id"
zeroProcessId=0
if [ "$domain_pdp_process_id" -gt "$zeroProcessId" ];
then
    echo "domain pdp is running"
else
    echo "domain pdp is not running"
fi;
exit;
```

please advise

Comment: Your script seems to be *syntactically* correct (although I'd suggest modifying it to use the exit status of `pgrep -fu pdpadmin "/home/pdpadmin/app/payara41/glassfish/domains/pdp/"` instead of trying to string match PIDs). Perhaps there are some non-printing characters that we're not seeing? Please run `cat -A ./qa_domain_pdp_auto_startup_script.sh` and [edit] your question to include the result.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if problem (on phone here) but you have extra `;` so I would restructure code to:

```
if [ "$domain_pdp_process_id" -gt "$zeroProcessId" ]; then
    echo "domain pdp is running"
else
    echo "domain pdp is not running"
fi
```

Or:

```
if [ "$domain_pdp_process_id" -gt "$zeroProcessId" ]
then
    echo "domain pdp is running"
else
    echo "domain pdp is not running"
fi
```